# Subtracting date stored as Bigint from GETDATE() to calculate current age

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am relatively new to SQL and need some help.  I have a third party ticketing database that stores dates as bigint.  I would like to be able calculate the age of tickets.  I can convert the bigint to date format using dateadd(s,CREATEDTIME/1000, '01-01-1970').  I am struggling with comparing it to the current date to calculate the age of the ticket.

I have tried datediff(DAY,(s,CREATEDTIME/1000, '01-01-1970'),GETDATE())) as 'ticket age' hoping that would work, but no luck.

Here is the full query at this point -

select
    dateadd(s,CREATEDTIME/1000, '01-01-1970') as 'Created_Date',
    datediff(DAY,(s,CREATEDTIME/1000, '01-01-1970'),GETDATE())) as 'ticket age',
    WORKORDERID as 'Request ID'
from WorkOrder

Comment: please tag your dbms name

Comment: Please post your entire query and table defs. See this reference: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically when counting days, due to how the datediff function works, I calculate the Hours, then divide by 24. (the datediff in days between Apr 4, 23:59 and Apr 5 00:01 is 1, which isn't always what people want).

As such, doing the query to get the numbers you appear to want gives something like this:

```
select dateadd(SECOND,CREATEDTIME/1000, '01-01-1970') as 'Created_Date',
CAST(DATEDIFF(HOUR,dateadd(SECOND,CREATEDTIME/1000, '01-01-1970'),GETDATE()) AS DECIMAL(15,4))/24 AS 'ticket age', 
WORKORDERID as 'Request ID' 
FROM WorkOrder
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about using:

```
dateadd(second, CREATEDTIME/1000, '1970-01-01') < getdate()
```

Or, if you want a comparison to the current *date* with no time component:

```
dateadd(second, CREATEDTIME/1000, '1970-01-01') < convert(date, getdate())
```

Note that this code spells out `second` and puts the date in the canonical YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: Both return the same error - Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Comment: Gordon only posted a fragment.  He assumes (as do I) that you know how to put that into an IF statement or a WHERE clause, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the actual posted question of "(How do I)  calculate the age of tickets?"   This is just checking to see whether a ticket's create date is less than today.